# Парсер гугл-картинок

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ

Парсю с помощью курл.
Поблема в том, что не знаю, как получить оригинальное изображение.

Если user agen стоит: `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0" ."; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR" ." 3.0.04506.30)`, то ДОМ получается такой:

```html
<td style="width:25%;word-wrap:break-word">
  <a href="/url?q=http://www.ki-kmv.ru/kuhni-klassicheskie/kuhni-klassicheskie-patina-s-serebrom/&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=PyN3VMyPHKvXyQPZ8oG4CA&amp;ved=0CBgQ9QEwAQ&amp;usg=AFQjCNFweKkal9x-iTYTDFO8-HBo8BvEeg">
    <img height="89" src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQrrkJwdzrM7chga6p1enXZlLUtYMG4gI6UXhHWD9E5PQcBKwbfsvM4Ny2m" width="149">
  </a>
  <br><cite title="ki-kmv.ru">ki-kmv.ru</cite>
  <br>patina-s-argentym1.jpg? ...
  <br>1000 Х 600; 548 КБ&nbsp;-&nbsp;jpg</td>
```

Ссылку на оригинальное изображение нигде в данном случае я не вижу.

Но в своем браузере выдача происходит по-другому, и ДОМ формируется другой. Пробовал вставить свой юзер-агент. На выходе имею:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/39.0.2171.65 Safari/537.36

```
mb,_.eb); }catch(e){_._DumpException(e)} try{ var pb,wb;_.nb=function(a){_.C(this,a,0,[])};_.v(_.nb,_.B);_.ob=function(){var a=_.G(_.H.K());return _.E(a,_.nb,11)};pb=function(a){_.C(this,a,0,[])};_.v(pb,_.B); var qb=[1,2,3,4,5,6,9,10,11,13,14,28,29,30,34,35,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,4
```

Comment: Отформатируй код, трудно читать его.

Answer (score 2):

И не увидите. "гугл" отдает картинки через редирект, по "печенкам" (cookie's).

**Обновление**

Посмотрите в сторону яндекса, если горит, он вроде отдает ссылки на картинки. http://yandex.ru/images/

А как быть с гуглом... У них чать картинок отдается все-таки как картинки

http://www.google.ru/imgres?imgurl=
**http%3A%2F%2Fp.cdn.scicasts.com%2Fimages%2Fstories%2Fproducts_tools%2Ffront_intel_cent2.jpg**
&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fscicasts.com%2Fscientific-computing%2F1837-processors%2F1941-intel-launches-new-intel-centrino-2-processor-technology%2F&h=271&w=270&tbnid=4WgCMXMNDqSf8M%3A&zoom=1&docid=m4NwXsdwiqCnDM&itg=1&ei=aSV4VNXQG6jmyQPUz4DQBA&tbm=isch&ved=0CBwQMygAMAA&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=692&page=1&start=0&ndsp=37

Comment: и как быть?
курлом ходить по всем ссылкам? Но ссылка дается после редиректа не на картинку. а на страницу с картинкой.  А на этой странице может быть много других картинок.